# CSS - Tinted Opacity

Tags: css

I am wondering if it is possible to apply tint to an opacity in css?

I have a PNG of various sizes. When the user hovers over the PNG, I want the PNG to change opacity to 0.5 with a tint of #000. According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_opacity.asp), you only have the ability to modify the opacity value and not the tint which is always set to #FFF.

I have tried to position a black box with its opacity set on top of my PNG and via css had it toggle between `display:none/block;` upon PNG hover. This did not work as my PNGs are not rectangular images and are various dimensions meaning the black box did not cover only my PNG.

Are there any alternative solutions to my problem?

Comment: "According to w3schools" - stop right there.

Comment: @Zenith - Do you mean w3schools is not a trustable source, or that there is no other alternative?

Comment: @Jon They are one of the worst resources on the world wide web

Comment: @Swordfish0321 Somebody noticed :)

Comment: [Obligatory w3fools reference](http://w3fools.com).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Webkit example: http://jsfiddle.net/5APXu/1/

```
div:hover { opacity: .5; -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) sepia(100%); }
```

This uses the CSS [filter property](http://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/#FilterProperty), which is starting to [gain support](http://caniuse.com/#search=filter). There are numerous effects possible, so you can probably achieve your original desire of black/gray tint.

- [Article many filter examples](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/filters/understanding-css/#toc-how)
- [Masking (alternate option)](http://thenittygritty.co/css-masking)

Comment: No problem. Keep in mind that browser support isn't complete, but that you can use old IE filters as a fallback, and/or also consider SVG filters (which have more browser support already). Depends on how much effort you want to put into it.

Comment: No, not unless you go to SVG images (which is potentially a lot more work). You can get similar effects using in IE (all versions) using IE filters: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847(v=vs.85).aspx. You might also look at masking the image using CSS (I'll see if I can dig up a reference).

Comment: Thank you. I'm also looking around as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a background color to the image on hover to get the effect you want. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/atbnn

```
img:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: #000;
}
```